# setvisibility(View.GONE) is working as INVISIBLE

Tags: android

its is the java code.

```
 if(currentword.hasImg()){
        img.setImageResource(currentword.getImgId());
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }else{
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

image view is invisible but it is still taking space.
please do help in setvisibility(view.gone)
setvisibility(View.GONE) is working as INVISIBLE.
image view taking space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:background="@color/tan_background">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:id="@+id/image" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        >
    <TextView
        tools:text="one"
        android:id="@+id/default_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/miwok_textview"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        tools:text="lutti" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: show your xml file

Comment: i m not able to upload it, how can i show u my xml file.

Comment: put code here as u have added those text use {} sign from editor for code.
check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: done sir ......

Comment: how did you check if `img.setVisibility(View.GONE);` is called at all? maybe an error is not with this code but with data(fx: `currentword.hasImg()` is always true)

Comment: i got answer thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, try to put youre layout height or width wrap content